# Joomla Installation drom server to local

Tags: joomla

I downloaded the joomla files from server which was in lamp folder now i am trying to configure it on my local in xampp server htdoc but white screen is showing, while i have updated the configuration file in joomla on my local. how to get rid of this problem?

Comment: You also need to copy the database and update the configuration.php file with the new database details.

Comment: Hi Neil, appreciate your comment, but i would like to inform you that i have done this (new database detail update) already, but still facing the issue. if you can help it will be much appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

Set value for "$error_reporting" in configuration.php to "maximum" and check white screen again.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use Akeeba BackUp joomla extension. It will help you back up your joomla installation, and restore your back up to local server easily.
Check this out https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/akeeba-backup/